# Noise generated when using mediarecorder + mediasource to broadcast live

Tags: javascript, media-source, web-mediarecorder

I tried to use mediarecorder and mediasource for live broadcast, the video can be played normally, but there will be noise every second.

The host sends the blob to the server, and the viewer requests the blob through ajax, and then splices it in the mediasource.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: {
            width: 1920,
            height: 1080
        },
        audio: true
    })
        .then(function (stream) {
            const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
                mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8,opus'
            });
            mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", handleDataAvailable);

            mediaRecorder.start(1000)
        })

        function handleDataAvailable(event) {
            event.data.arrayBuffer().then((buffer) => {
            socket.send(buffer)
        })
```

Receiving end：

```
const video = document.getElementById("video")

const mediaSource = new MediaSource();

const url = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
video.src = url;

let start = 0
let sourceBuffer;
mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", function () {
    sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm;codecs=vp8,opus')
    sourceBuffer.mode = 'sequence'
    sourceBuffer.addEventListener("updateend", function () {
        getBuffer(start, start + 1)
        console.log(video.getVideoPlaybackQuality());
    })
    getBuffer()
});

const arrayOfBlobs = [];

function getBuffer() {
    window.axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/buffer',
        params: {
            start: start,
            end: start + 1
        },
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    }).then((response) => {
        arrayOfBlobs.push(response.data)
        appendToSourceBuffer()
        start += 1
    })
}

function appendToSourceBuffer() {
    if (
        mediaSource.readyState === "open" &&
        sourceBuffer &&
        sourceBuffer.updating === false
    ) {
        const buf = arrayOfBlobs.shift()
        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buf);
    }
}
```

What can I do to eliminate the noise?

Comment: If you keep everything on the same machine, without the requests, does the same problem occur? Do you hear the same "noise" in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2sp40db/)? Also, could you describe a bit more this "noise"? Is it like white noise or a clip? There is something I find a bit weird in your code, nothing ensures that `appendToSourceBuffer` actually gets a `buf` to process (the sourceend + fetch may very well take less than one second). But if that was an issue, then it would just throw, not produce "noise"...

Comment: @Kaiido Hi, thanks for your help. I wrote a demo to send and receive buffers in the same machine and browser. But there is still noise.I used the virtual camera manycam to play a video.Does the reason come from it?Demo:https://codepen.io/hechuangzhiyun/pen/MWjzJER

Comment: Not sure, but on my computer there is no particular "noise". What if you simply keep all the chunks in the Array and build a single standalone file from these chunks? Does the resulting file also expose the "noise"?

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks a lot.It should be the reason for the virtual camera software.